# Missing attributes for links and other types of elements in pandoc

Tags: haskell, pandoc

I am trying to use [`pandoc`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc) (with [`hakyll`](http://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/), but this is probably not important) to achieve the following:

1. Read a markdown file.
2. Convert it to HTML.
3. Add a `target="_blank"` attribute to every link that is automatically produced.

The problem is that the [definition of `Inline`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-types/docs/Text-Pandoc-Definition.html#t:Inline) in `pandoc` seems to support attributes only for some types of `Inline`s, e.g., for `Span` and `Code`, and not for others, e.g., for `Link` and `Image`.

Is this an arbitrary limitation of `pandoc`, or was it made on purpose for some reason that I do not understand?  Furthermore, is there a way to achieve what I want, without resorting to low-level string processing or to using the `RawInline` constructor?

---

Here is a MWE:

```
import Text.Pandoc
import Text.Pandoc.Walk

fixLinks :: Pandoc -> Pandoc
fixLinks = walk fixLink
  where fixLink (Link inlines (url, title)) =
          Link inlines (url, "I want to add a target=_blank to this link!")
        fixLink inline = inline

main = do
  let md = "This is a link to [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)."
  (putStrLn . writeHtmlString def . fixLinks . readMarkdown def) md
```

Answer (score 3):

Image and link attributes are documented as a feature 'not in Pandoc' on the [Pandoc vs Multimarkdown Wiki](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Pandoc-vs-Multimarkdown#image-and-link-attributes) page.

There are open issues around this, like [Permit adding attributes to all Markdown elements #684](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/684). I didn't see attached code/pull requests to implement them when I looked.

If you want to add a `target="_blank"` attribute to auto-generated links, I think you'll need to use a workaround in the meantime. (And note that you might not need to use raw string processing if you post-process the HTML with a non-Pandoc HTML parser.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a [pandoc filter](http://github.com/jgm/pandocfilters).

The [pandoc-attributes](http://github.com/aaren/pandoc-attributes) filter can read and write attributes in both `markdown` and `html`